Synchronization issue between video frame timestamps and sensor data (rotation vector) in Kotlin
Description:
I am developing an Android application in Kotlin that performs the following tasks:

Video capture: Saves the video and the current timestamp of each frame into a .csv file.
Sensor data capture (rotation vector): Saves yaw, pitch, roll values along with the current timestamp into another .csv file.

Configuration:

Video capture frequency: 30Hz.
Rotation vector update frequency: 250Hz (though the thread writes the data to the file at approximately 80Hz).

Problem:
When trying to synchronize the timestamps of video frames with the sensor data to correlate each frame with the corresponding yaw, pitch, and roll values, I noticed that the timestamps do not align directly. To achieve proper synchronization, I have to add an offset of about 160ms to the video timestamps.
This value was determined empirically, but I don’t understand the source of this delay. The same function is used to capture timestamps for both the video and the sensor data, so I expected them to be directly comparable.
I need help to understand:

The "VideoRecordEvent.Status" method does not return me the correct time of the frame capture?
Why is there a 160ms discrepancy between the video and sensor timestamps?
Is there a more accurate way to correct or compensate for this delay?

Part of the code that captures the video and its timestamp:
val enableAudio = false
recording = videoCapture.output
    .prepareRecording(this, mediaStoreOutput)
    .apply {
        if (enableAudio && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this@MainActivity,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            withAudioEnabled()
        }
    }
    .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)) { recordEvent ->
        when (recordEvent) {
            is VideoRecordEvent.Start -> {
                base_time = System.currentTimeMillis()
                isRecordingVideo = true
            }
            is VideoRecordEvent.Status -> {
                val time = recordEvent.recordingStats.recordedDurationNanos / 1_000_000
                val uriTimestampCopy = uriTimestamp
                if(uriTimestampCopy != null){
                    addTimestampDataToCsv(uriTimestampCopy, base_time+time)
                }

            }
            is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                isRecordingVideo = false

            }
        }
    }

Part of the code that captures the rotation vector data and its timestamp
private fun CSV_capture(){
    val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    executor.execute {
        val uriRotVectorCopy = uriRotVector
        while(isRecord && (uriRotVectorCopy != null)) {
            addRotationDataToCsv(uriRotVectorCopy)
        }

    }

}

fun addRotationDataToCsv(uri: Uri) {
    val Lyaw = myaw
    val Lpitch = mpitch
    val Lroll = mroll
    val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val resolver = contentResolver
    try {
        val outputStream: OutputStream? = resolver.openOutputStream(uri, "wa")
        outputStream?.let { stream ->
            val data = "$Lyaw,$Lpitch,$Lroll,$timestamp\n"
            stream.write(data.toByteArray())
            stream.flush()
            stream.close()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

I have already tried the following approaches to address the issue:

Saving the rotation vector data immediately after capturing each video frame.
Reducing the camera resolution and disabling audio capture to try to minimize latency.

However, none of these attempts produced a significant improvement. The timestamps captured for the video frames still don’t seem to correspond to the real timestamps of the frames.
